# All usages of a variable/parameter in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Is there an easy way to figure out all places where a variable or parameter is being utilised in annylogic. Trying to locate where each variable is used can be a pain during debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just "ignore" it in the properties and compile the model.

[image]

You will get a list of errors for all places where it is called. Double-click on each error and AnyLogic even takes you there :)
[image]

Else, you can also use the AnyLogic search functionality.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in order to get some relief for that pain if your model is too big, all your variables should be private and you create setters, so each time you change your variable, you required to use a set function.

This doesn't solve your question, but it tells you what to do in future models to make it easier for you

check this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNBfdB6YF7o